# Adding the same IXMLNode multiiple times in a TXMLDocument

Tags: xml, delphi, txmldocument

I've noticed that it is possible to add the same node multiple times into the same TXMLDocument - is this a good idea?

```
  n := XMLDocument1.CreateElement('Test', '');
  XMLDocument1.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Add(n);
  XMLDocument1.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Add(n);
  n.Text := 'fool me once...';
```

The node test will appear multiple times in the tree

Edit: To make my question clear - Will it cause any problems if I add an IXMLNode multiple times in a TXMLDocument?

Comment: @Ken White.  Yes.  My question is more if it is going to cause me any grief by doing this.  Presumably if I have a large number of identical nodes then this will make things more memory efficient, but are there any side effects in doing this.

Comment: +1 - Thanks for the edit to clarify. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding node to a document you won't lose a reference to just added node, so there's nothing wrong to do it several times. If it's a good idea is then just a design question - if you need to add several same nodes to your document at one time, then it's the best way to do so.